# Doing a switcheroo with a motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

I'd like to get a more compact case, such as as a [Fractal Design Node 304](http://www.fractal-design.com/home/product/cases/node-series/node-304-black).

However, that case is for mini-ITX mobos while I'm currently using a [micro-ATX mobo](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M2N68AM_PLUS/specifications/), and I don't have the courage to reinstall Windows and all my apps.

So I was wondering if I could just plug my current Windows 7 system disk onto the new mobo and expect Windows to resume working after downloading new drivers?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I meant: "After Windows starts in basic mode (low VGA, no sound, no network), ...". I'll give it a shot.

Comment: (In particular, consider following the procedure outlined in the answer there, as it can be hit-or-miss, despite my [now deleted] comment.)

Comment: before you switch motherboards do  **sysprep /generalize** shutdown the computer. Move hard drive to new motherboard and boot.

Comment: What is *"switcheroo"*?